# Encoding by LabelEncoder

Tags: python, pandas

I have this csv file and I want to encode a column in another column by a different name by LabelEncoder but it's not possible.  I'm really new to this and I can't figure it out. The error says that it's not defined

[image]

I need to encode the sex column here and dataframe is called tips
Encode the categorical feature 'sex' by using LabelEncoder. Store encoded sex in a new column named 'sex_code'.

Comment: You need to share the code that you use and the full text of the error so that we can help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`LabelEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) is simple if you follow the example of the documentation:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# Create a Minimal Working Example
cols = ['total_bill', 'tip', 'sex', 'smoker']
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')[cols]

# Load encoder then convert as code
le = LabelEncoder()
tips['sex_code'] = le.fit_transform(tips['sex'])
```

Output:

```
>>> tips.head()
   total_bill   tip     sex smoker  sex_code
0       16.99  1.01  Female     No         0
1       10.34  1.66    Male     No         1
2       21.01  3.50    Male     No         1
3       23.68  3.31    Male     No         1
4       24.59  3.61  Female     No         0
```